# I want to make a part, created by a script, play a sound

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I've got a script which when picks a remoteEvent, fired by a local script when firing a raycast, creates a part where the raycast hit (raycast.Position, labelled as "impacto")

```
local remoteEvent = script.Parent.esquirlaEvent
local ruido = script.Parent.ruidoEvent
local tool = script.Parent
local debris = game:GetService("Debris")
local material = Enum.Material

remoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, startPosition, impacto, colordobjeto, materialdobjeto)

    local function crearescombros(startPosition, impacto)

        local visual = Instance.new("Part")
        visual.Name = "esquirla"
        visual.Parent = game.Workspace.esquirlas
        visual.Anchored = true
        visual.CanCollide = false
        visual.Transparency = .5
        visual.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
        
        if materialdobjeto ~= material.Metal then
            visual.Size = Vector3.new(2, 2, 2)
            visual.Material = material.Plastic
            
        elseif materialdobjeto == Enum.Material.Metal then
            visual.Size = Vector3.new(1, 1, 1)
            visual.Material = material.Neon
            
        end
        
        
        if materialdobjeto == Enum.Material.Concrete then
            visual.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Medium stone grey")
            
        elseif materialdobjeto == Enum.Material.Brick then
            visual.BrickColor = colordobjeto
            
        elseif materialdobjeto == Enum.Material.Metal then
            visual.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("New Yeller")
            
        elseif materialdobjeto == Enum.Material.Grass then
            visual.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Brown")
            
        end

        visual.CFrame = CFrame.lookAt(impacto, startPosition)

        
        wait(.1)
        visual.Transparency = .8
        
        debris:AddItem(visual, 0.2)
    end
    

    
    crearescombros(startPosition, impacto)
end)
```

Well, I'd like this part instance, visual, play a sound.

I've tried creating a sound istance inside of the local function, but it doesn't work all that good. Although the sound DOES play when "visual" appears, it stops playing as soon as the part dissapears, 0.2 seconds, cutting the audio midway, making it bothering.
This is the attempt:

```
local remoteEvent = script.Parent.esquirlaEvent
local ruido = script.Parent.ruidoEvent
local tool = script.Parent
local debris = game:GetService("Debris")
local material = Enum.Material

remoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, startPosition, impacto, colordobjeto, materialdobjeto)

    local function crearescombros(startPosition, impacto)

        local visual = Instance.new("Part")
        visual.Name = "esquirla"
        visual.Parent = game.Workspace.esquirlas
        visual.Anchored = true
        visual.CanCollide = false
        visual.Transparency = .5
        visual.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
        
        if materialdobjeto ~= material.Metal then
            visual.Size = Vector3.new(2, 2, 2)
            visual.Material = material.Plastic
            
        elseif materialdobjeto == Enum.Material.Metal then
            visual.Size = Vector3.new(1, 1, 1)
            visual.Material = material.Neon
            
        end
        
        
        if materialdobjeto == Enum.Material.Concrete then
            visual.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Medium stone grey")
            
        elseif materialdobjeto == Enum.Material.Brick then
            visual.BrickColor = colordobjeto
            
        elseif materialdobjeto == Enum.Material.Metal then
            visual.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("New Yeller")
            
        elseif materialdobjeto == Enum.Material.Grass then
            visual.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Brown")
            
        end

        visual.CFrame = CFrame.lookAt(impacto, startPosition)
        
        local sonido = Instance.new("Sound")
        sonido.Parent = visual
        sonido.SoundId = "rbxassetid://15179448200"
        sonido:Play()
        sonido.Volume = 5
        sonido.MaxDistance = 50
        
        wait(.1)
        visual.Transparency = .8
        
        sonido:Destroy()
        
        debris:AddItem(visual, 0.2)
    end
    

    
    crearescombros(startPosition, impacto)
end)
```

Any help is aprecciated and will be taked in count.

Comment: I don't know much about Roblox, but I assume the sound would stop when you `:Destroy` it? If you need to destroy it, perhaps do that after it finished via the `Ended` event. Or possibly `PlayOnRemove` can be used? (This might be needed if the parent ends up being destroyed before the sound finishes anyway.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on PlayOnRemove ? how is it used? the situation in which it's used is the one I'm in actually.

Comment: I only know what I read in the documentation. It looks like you don't need to `:Play()`, so maybe `:Destroy()` instead (without waiting) after `sonido.PlayOnRemove = true`. (Probably set all the sound properties before `:Play()` or `:Destroy()`)